# Benign "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted" error while using Active Directory Users and Computers

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a single Windows Server 2012 R2 Active Directory Domain Controller for domain `MYDOMAIN`. I want to perform remote administration of the Active Directory from a workstation that is not joined to the domain. To achieve this, I'm running the Active Directory Users and Computers tool using `runas /netonly user:MYDOMAIN\Adrian.Hofman`.

Once in Active Directory Users and Computers, I connect to `MYDOMAIN` by entering the IP address of the domain controller in the `Change Domain Controller...` dialog.

This works fine. However, when I do certain operations (for example, creating a new user, or going to the `Member Of` tab of a users `Properties` dialog), I get the following error dialog:

`The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.`

The error dialog appears to be completely benign - after the dialog is dismissed, operation continues normally and successfully.

However, I'm deploying these tools to non-technical users, and I'm concerned the error messages will cause them to lose confidence in the system.

Any pointers on how I can make the error messages go away?

**Edit:** I've tried the following:

- I run `dcdiag` on the domain controller; all tests passed; there didn't appear to be any useful information.
- I tried using Active Directory Users and Computers from a machine that *is* joined to the domain, and i *don't* get the error. I still need to be able to use AD U&C from a non-domain machine, though.

Comment: Is the non-domain PC pointed to the DC for DNS?

Comment: No, it's accessing the domain via the IP address of the DC.

Comment: You could try pointing it at the DC for DNS, there could be things attempting to load via the domain name.

Comment: +1 old thread but having the exact same issue as @AdrianHofman but connecting to Server 2016, not sure if this was ever resolved? I'm using Server Manager (with machine added to trusted list) to connect to a DC on a different domain over VPN. DNS, and DHCP mmc snap-ins work fine. ADUC though, gives the same issue as described above. Have tried creating a forward lookup zone in the local DNS in case of DNS issue but this doesn't help. Guessing maybe something to do with NetBIOS or other broadcast traffic.

Comment: Still a problem 8 years later sadly. Kind of bizarre that it's still a thing. Adding a DNS hosts entry seems to have made things worse not better. Can use the domain instead of IP for the DC but it's slower to open... Odd. But I'm certainly not messing with the actual DNS server itself.